# Avoid react-router goBack() going out of application

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using vanilla React with react-router to build a simple master-detail SPA.
In the list page, i used `push(*route*)` to navigate the user to a detail view, a back button on the detail view then calls `goBack()` to navigate the user to the list view.

The reason for me to use the `goBack()` function instead of `push('/list')` is to allow the user to navigate back to the list view without losing filtering/pagination parameters (e.g. /list/1/10?q=abc).

The problem I have is, if the user started the browser from e.g. Google, then copy/paste the detail view url into the address bar, the `goBack()` function will take them back to Google as Google was his last history.

Is there a way to check the `goBack()` destination and decide to perform `goBack()` based on whether the user will exit the application?

Answer (score 0):

We can use router to push the query param in the list page as states to the destination page, which is available only if the detail page is navigated from the list page.

The state is only maintained within the current application scope. Copy pasting the url into another browser tab will lose this state.

Example: 
List page navigation to detail page

```
router.push({
    pathname: '/users/12',
    query: { modal: true },
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
})
```

Detail page:

```
if (this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.params) {
    navigateBackUsingParams(this.props.location.state.params);
} else {
    navigateBackWithHardcodedUrl();
}
```